# ajax / jquery trying to append new options to select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, html-select

I'm trying to load a list of locations via ajax / jquery.  Each time I type a letter into the input I get the first respponse back with subsequent responses appended. I've tried using .html('') and .empty() but not getting the desired results. I want the list to clear each time and return the new input results.

[image: HTML]

[image: ajax]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You mean clear all the previous `option` before appending the new results?

Comment: yes, I've looked at a bunch of previous answers but when I used the suggestions .html() I only got one result back in the list and using .empty() gave me no results

Comment: `html("")` with empty string pased in should work, empty() as well

Answer (score 0):

See this my example , clear select first by `empty` and then append new `option` value !!!

```js
$('#ss').empty();
$('#ss').append($('<option>').html('test'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ss">
<option>$$</option>
<option>55</option>
</select>
```

Comment: have the same problem with this, I only get one item back in the list,  unable to attach a screenshot but I typed in North which should return stacks of results but I only get one

Comment: @sam80e You should do empty select outside of `for loop` ! not inside loop !

Answer (score 0):

Select all `option` and `.remove()` should work

```js
function clearSelectFields(){
  $('#selectField')
    .children() // Select children of the select field
    .remove();  // Remove all the selected element
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="selectField">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<button onclick="clearSelectFields()">Clear</button>
```

Comment: thankyou but what I'm actually trying to do here is type the next letter, for example if I'm search for North I type N (get everything starting with N) Type O clear the things starting with N and return things with NO